# Is there any way to change the foreground of a TextBlock using MultiBinding?

Tags: wpf, textblock, multibinding

I need to change the foreground of a text block based on three properties. I used Multibinding with a converter to do it. The converter returns the value correctly, but the foreground is not changing.

```
<TextBlock
  Margin="10,1,0,1"
  Grid.Column="1"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
  FontSize="15.5"
  Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"
  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <TextBlock.FontWeight>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FontWeightConverter}">
         <Binding ElementName="MessageCountBorder" Path="Visibility"/>
         <Binding Path="IsMuted"/>
      </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.FontWeight>
  <TextBlock.Foreground>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ForegroundConverter}">
          <Binding Path="TypeId"/>
          <Binding Path="IsMuted"/>
          <Binding Path="UserOnlineStatus"/>
      </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

I'm using this TextBlock in a ListView. And the properties I'm binding to the Foreground are from a model.

The **TextBlockForegroundConverter** converter is as follows.

```
public class TextBlockForegroundConverter: IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Value[0] ==> For TypeId
            // Value[1] ==> For IsMuted
            // Value[2] ==> For UserOnlineStatus

            try
            {
                var typeId = (int)values[0];
                var isMuted = (bool)values[1];
                var userOnlineStatus = (int)values[2];

                if (typeId == 1)
                    return isMuted ? Brushes.Gray : Brushes.White;
                else
                {
                    if (isMuted || userOnlineStatus == 2 || userOnlineStatus == 5)
                        return Brushes.Gray;
                    else
                        return Brushes.White;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
            return Brushes.White;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: return "white" will return a string white rather than a brush. At least in that circumstance, your converter cannot be returning the correct value.

Comment: I tried returning brushes and also strings. There is no use @Andy.

Answer (score 0):

Both the XAML and the converter code look good. Actually, the converter returns a string in one of the cases, which is not an acceptable output, but as far as I can see, this condition is not reachable, so it should be fine. My guess is that one of the properties "TypeId", "IsMuted"... does not raise the [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) event, when its value is updated. Bindings will initially work even INPC interface is not implemented, but their future values will never change, when the bound property is updated.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isMuted;

    public bool IsMuted
    {
        get { return isMuted; }
        set
        {
            if (isMuted != value)
            {
                isMuted = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsMuted");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prN)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prN));
    }
}
```

Comment: That might not do any good. We are just using those 3 properties in converter for the foreground color. As per my knowledge, there is no need to use INPC interface here, unless we are changing the property values. Anyways, Thanks for the help zaphod-ii.

Comment: You can try opening the Output window and look for any binding errors. Ensure that they are enabled in Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > Data Binding.